# Ionic unfocus searchbar placeholder to align left

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4, searchbar

I would like to know if it's possible to align Ionic searchbar placeholder to the left side when unfocus?

[image: place holder is currently align centered]

as of right now the placeholder is currently centered when unfocus

**HTML**

```
<ion-searchbar
  slot="bottom"
  mode="ios"
  autocomplete="off"
  autocorrect="off"
  spellcheck="false"
  animated="true"
  debounce="500"
  clearIcon="close"
  [placeholder]="placeholder"
  [(ngModel)]="search"
  (ionChange)="runSearch()"
></ion-searchbar>
```

**CSS**

```
ion-searchbar {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 56, 100, 0.4);
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 8px 0 12px;
  --border-radius: 6px;
  --background: white;
  --placeholder-color: red;

  text-align: start !important; // not working
  text-align: left !important; // not working
  align-items: flex-start; // not working

  &::placeholder {
    text-align: left; // not working
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Small Update to evans answer that works for Ionic React Apps

Place code at top of variables.css

```css
ion-searchbar {
  --background: "black"
}

.searchbar-search-icon.sc-ion-searchbar-ios {
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}
.searchbar-input.sc-ion-searchbar-ios {
  padding-left: 30px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of right now (Ionic 4) the solution I found is to add in `app.scss`

```
// Force align searchbar text left 
ion-searchbar {
  .searchbar-search-icon.sc-ion-searchbar-ios.ios.hydrated{
    margin-left: 0 !important;
  }
  .searchbar-input.sc-ion-searchbar-ios {
    padding-left: 30px !important;
  }
}
```

this will force the placeholder & icon align to the left corner when *unfocused*.